# expected struct foo* but argument is of type struct foo* for function pointers

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, function-pointers

I have two typedefs for function pointers and two structs, `struct pipe_s` and `struct pipe_buffer_s` defined as so:

```c
typedef void (*pipe_inf_t)(struct pipe_buffer_s *);
typedef void (*pipe_outf_t)(struct pipe_buffer_s *);

struct
pipe_buffer_s
{
    size_t cnt;      /* number of chars in buffer */
    size_t len;      /* length of buffer */
    uint8_t *mem;    /* buffer */
};

struct
pipe_s
{
    struct pipe_buffer_s buf;
    uint8_t state;
    pipe_inf_t in;   /* input call */
    pipe_outf_t out; /* output call */
};
```

In my implementation, I have a function that attempts to call the function `in`:

```c
void
pipe_receive(struct pipe_s *pipe)
{
    pipe_inf_t in;
    in = pipe->in;
    in(&pipe->buf);
}
```

But I am getting the strange error:

> pipe.c:107:5: note: expected 'struct pipe_buffer_s *' but argument is of type 'struct pipe_buffer_s *'

This makes no sense to me. As far as I can *tell*, I haven't goofed up and tried to use a struct of undefined length because I'm only using pointers here. I think I may have done something wrong with my typedef...

Changing the typedef to `typedef void (*pipe_inf_t)(int);` and calling `in(5)` works just fine however.

I get the same error if I move `in` and `out` into the `pipe_buffer_s` struct and call them from there so location doesn't seem to matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: @wildplasser I'm writing an OS in ANSI C. It's `gcc` with `std=c89`.

Comment: You'll need an opaque pointer before the pointer typedefs. Or change the order.

Comment: Is that the only warning or error you get? I get more than that. All the errors are fixed by moving the typedefs to be after `struct pipe_buffer_s` as the typedefs need that struct definition.

Comment: @kaylum Oh my gosh, you're absolutely right, that's what fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the definition of `pipe_buffer_s` **before** referring to it. This can be an incomplete type:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct pipe_buffer_s; // Incomplete definition

typedef void (*pipe_inf_t)(struct pipe_buffer_s *);
typedef void (*pipe_outf_t)(struct pipe_buffer_s *);

struct
pipe_buffer_s
{
    size_t cnt;      /* number of chars in buffer */
    size_t len;      /* length of buffer */
    uint8_t *mem;    /* buffer */
};

struct
pipe_s
{
    struct pipe_buffer_s buf;
    uint8_t state;
    pipe_inf_t in;   /* input call */
    pipe_outf_t out; /* output call */
};

// In my implementation, I have a function that attempts to call the function in:

void
pipe_receive(struct pipe_s *pipe)
{
    pipe_inf_t in;
    in = pipe->in;
    in(&pipe->buf);
}
```

Comment: That is indeed the case. I may have had it well defined but I didn't have it defined quick enough... Thank you very much.